# React Concat State

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand my folderPathName state is not updating.
I am concatenating an array onto the the folderPathName every time a button is clicked. The data from folder is correct but every time i go back into the event folderPathNames is null and has not updated with the previous state from the last button click.

```js
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      folderPathNames: []
    };
  }


  handleFolderClick = (event,id) => {
    const { folderPathNames } = this.state;
    const folderId = event.currentTarget.dataset["folder"]
    const folder = this.state.model.folderDictionary[folderId]
    let folderPath = [];
    folderPath = folderPathNames.concat([folder])
    this.setState({ ...this.state, folderPathNames: folderPath })
    if (!!folder) {
      this.props.listFolders(folder, this.state.model)
      this.props.listDocument(+folderId, this.state.model)
    }

    this.setState({ enableCheckBox: false })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This line will presumably end up with the existing key-values from this.state, which would lead to duplicate values for `folderPathNames`, and I'd guess Javascript picks the first value of that key?

`this.setState({ folderPathNames: folderPath })`

Potentially change it to:

`this.setState({ ...this.state, folderPathNames: folderPath })`

Unless for some reason you need to pass existing state back into a setState call?

Comment: Sorry i am not too sure what you are saying. I am trying to append a folder onto folderpathNames each time a folder is clicked on. so what i am doing is getting the state of folderpathNames and then adding the new folder onto it. also you have the same code line for the potentially change it to. thanks for the help

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 Unless I'm mistaken `this.state` already is of the form `{folderPathNames: ['some','state']}`, so`{...this.state, folderPathNames: ['new', 'some', 'state'}` would equate to trying to do `{folderPathNames: ['some','state'], folderPathNames: ['new','some','state']}` and the javascript interpreter would ignore the second declaration, at a guess.